# Visual Studio Database Edition memory problems and auto recompile

Tags: visual-studio, datadude

Currently storing database of a large application with 2,000 stored procedures in Visual Studio Database Edition.

The problem I'm having is that when I try and edit a stored procedure, Visual Studio becomes unresponsive and it can take 30 seconds to type in a single keyword.

What I believe is that Visual Studio is attempting to auto recompile the project/solution.  Does anyone know of a workaround, can this be switched off?

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look @ [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/vstsdb/thread/5f5fa150-c015-43a3-ab59-77737fdfb820) post, which talks about a known issue with the *.dbml file and that the suppression of warnings doesn't always aid in the problem.  The original poster does post a workaround.

Comment: Thanks Ben

It kinds of looks at the symptom of the problem with the suppression of warnings.  But it still appears that VSTS attempts to build the application on the fly.

Would be nice to switch it off altogether.  I'm still testing to see if it resolves the problem entirely.

Comment: No problem.  Please follow-up to let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I'll give you kudos for what it's worth - would love to be able a final solution for this.  Will be interesting to see if this is somthing that happens on VS 2010.